# Php dbase return misleading column count

Tags: php, foxpro, dbase

I have to convert desktop application to saas

This application storing its data using foxpro ( *.dbf file )

Problem arise when i try to update the row inside the dbf file

It always return me an error: `dbase_replace_record(): Wrong number of fields specified`

When i run `dbase_numfields( $db )`, i got 244 fields;

But when i run `count( dbase_get_record_with_names( $db, 1 ) )`,
It will always return 242 ( missing 2 column )

Is there something that going on that im not aware of while working with *.dbf file?

Answer (score 0):

`count( dbase_get_record_with_names( $db, 0 ) )`

Not 100% sure, but shouldn't you start counting 0,1,2....

Comment: `1` is referring to first record/row inside `*.dbf file`

Comment: from what i understand, 0 exists as a record but doesn't contain any values, so maybe that throws your count off

Comment: im only interested with column count, not the row count